# problem with the input at ZINCPharmer

Tags: docking

I need to search for possible inhibitors for an enzyme. So I found the website [ZINCPharmer](http://zincpharmer.csb.pitt.edu/) and a [publication](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3394271/) which seems to help me out with my problem. When I enter the website I cannot submit any pbd files or submit the job.
Does anybody knows if the site is down or so?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved so its about the firewall, the admin has sorted it. It was not possible by the user itself. Something was blocked by institute firewall.